# android-on navigation drawer item click get data from database and populate another list

Tags: java, android, listview, navigation-drawer, onitemclicklistener

My application contains a Navigation Drawer and i use its list items as a menu, by clicking on  which help in retrieving data from database and populating my listview in main activity...
I want to send a query to a database function based on the item clicks of drawer list and based on the query result my another list view in main activity will be populated..

Basically what i tried till now is assigning a different string holding the query based on the item click into the String type variable "query" and passing it as a parameter to a function of database who processes it as a rawQuery and retrieves result...
Due to some errors which am not able to detect it is throwing Null Pointer Exception...

Following is the code for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private CharSequence mTitle;

private Cursor c;
public MyDatabaseHandler dbOpen;
private String query; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mNavigationDrawerFragment = 
    (NavigationDrawFragment) 
     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();


    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    dbOpen = new MyDatabaseHandler(this);
    c = dbOpen.getListContent(query);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.topic_list_each_row,
    c,new String[]{MyDatabaseHandler.KEY_UTOPICNAME,MyDatabaseHandler.KEY_UNAME },
    new int[] {R.id.topicname,R.id.unitname} ,0));
    }

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
//here where i have thought of passing string into query variable
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            query = "SELECT * FROM cosmtable ORDER BY utopicname";
             break;
             ...............
             ..............
                }}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));}}}
```

The activity_main file is-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.pockettutsforcosm.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:dividerHeight="10dp">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.pockettutsforcosm.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help me  out in finding a way to achieve the results..
If further details needed then please let me know..
Thank You

**UPDATE**
One thing i Figured out in this is i was trying to write the query at wrong place i.e., the query variable shouldn't be assigned with a value at onAttach event...

SO i changed the code in Main Activity as follows-

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      //      .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position))
        //    .commit();

    try
    {
        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
            query = "SELECT * FROM cosmtable ORDER BY topic_name";
            c = dbOpen.getListContent(query);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.topic_list_each_row,c,
            new String[]{MyDatabasehandler.KEY_UTOPICNAME,MyDatabaseHandler.KEY_UNAME},
            new int[] {R.id.topicname,R.id.unitname} ,0));
            break;
             .............................................

        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error on fragment", "creating the mainScreen");
    }
    finally {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1 ))
                .commit();}}
```

And after doing this the content to be loaded from first item click of navigation drawer doesn't appears when the application is first launched....
it appears only when the item is clicked...
i want it to appear on application launch...

Do i need to create separate methods in my database handler class to return separate query results for each switch case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what i did is i created a separate function which can manipulate the query string accordingly the position of each element of navigation drawer and then it is being passed to get cursor data function in database handler and then the query results being back thrown to the simple cursor adapter in MainActivity....

The other thing is did for the problem of blank screen when the application is launched is i called the same function which manipulating the database query for the first element...

This is giving me my desired outputs..
Still if there is another good to go method out there then i am open to know that approach too.
for till now i will accept this as a answer..